# Lucene.net 3.0.3 unexpected ParseException

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I implemented a search using a RamDirectory. The directory is filled once and from there on only read.

Sometimes i get error i can't explain (see below) . Most of the time they say  the query can't get parsed but the query **venlo OR venlo*** looks good for the case.

I also don't under stand what is meant by `Encountered " <TERM> "marburg "` as marburg is a value in the index but it isn't part of the query...

```
 Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.ParseException: Cannot parse 'venlo OR
 venlo\*': Encountered " <TERM> "marburg "" at line 1, column 0. Was
 expecting one of: <NOT> ... "+" ... "-" ... "(" ... "*" ... <QUOTED>
 ... <TERM> ... <PREFIXTERM> ...
```

Here Another exception that occured once when parsing the `nice~`

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
     Parameter name: length
     at System.String.CtorCharArrayStartLength(Char[] value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
     at Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.FastCharStream.get_Image() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\QueryParser\FastCharStream.cs:line 107
     at Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParserTokenManager.JjFillToken() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\QueryParser\QueryParserTokenManager.cs:line 1313
     at Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParserTokenManager.GetNextToken() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\QueryParser\QueryParserTokenManager.cs:line 1388
     at Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.Jj_ntk() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\QueryParser\QueryParser.cs:line 1929
     at Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.Modifiers() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\QueryParser\QueryParser.cs:line 1248
     at Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.Query(String field) in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\QueryParser\QueryParser.cs:line 1300
     at Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.Parse(String query) in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\QueryParser\QueryParser.cs:line 224
     at SR.BusPortal.Graph.Lucene.Cities.LuceneCityReader.ParseQuery(String searchQuery)
```

My Code looks like this

```
 private static Query ParseQuery(string searchQuery, Analyzer analyzer)
 {
    var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(global::Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, new[] { "SimpleName", "SimpleNativeName" }, analyzer)
    {
        FuzzyMinSim = 0.3f,
        AllowLeadingWildcard = false,
        MultiTermRewriteMethod = MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_QUERY_REWRITE
    };

    Query query;

    try
    {
        query = parser.Parse(searchQuery.Trim());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        query = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(searchQuery.Trim()));
    }
    return query;
}
```

As input the method gets **venlo OR venlo*** and a `SimpleAnalyzer`

Comment: What is your intention when you pass `venlo OR venlo*` as search string?

Comment: Searching for cities starting with the string or containing it. Why ? Is there something wrong with the query format ? Also with a second run the query succeeds so i assume the problem shoudn't  be realted to the query it self

Comment: I had a look at the log and found one more error entry with the query nice~ .